# Samsung tablet keeps asking to allow data access when plugging to PC by USB

Tags: usb, tablet

I cannot access data on my tablet by USB, because when I plug it in, it keeps popping a dialog to allow access, when I pick allow, the dialog pops up again, and so on endlessly.

This is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A, my PC is on Ubuntu.

**Update:** After some more tests, I determined that if when I plug the tablet to the PC by USB, the tablet screen is turned on, it works fine. However if I plug the tablet with the screen off, the issue described above occurs.

Comment: Please add a screenshot

Comment: @beeshyams The dialog shows on the tablet, I cannot take a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe the cable keeps disconnecting, and therefore it's doing it. Try a different cable

Comment: @Abochur I tried three different cables. All of them work fine on another device. Also, the tablet charges fine if I plug it (using the same cable) to a power outlet.

Comment: Could it be the USB port instead? This really does sound most likely to be caused by the cable repeatedly disconnecting and reconnecting, which is a common failure mode.

Comment: @DanHulme That was my first thought too. But the same USB port on the PC, with the same cable, plugs succesfully to my phone (which is also Samsung). And the port on the tablet works fine when charging on a power outlet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround more than a fix, but it works for me on another Samsung device.

Install Samsung SideSync app from the Google play store on your device, then install Samsung SideSync app on your PC (http://www.samsung.com/sidesync).

After one more "allow access" popup, it won't ask again as the SideSync app will keep the allow access permission open.

Comment: how about Mac OS host?